# Configuring no extra empty line between selectors with Stylelint

Tags: css, frontend, stylelint

I'm looking for help in configuring Stylelint options. I would like to set a rule that no empty lines are allowed between selectors in a list of selectors:

```
&:focus,
 
&:hover,

&.active {
  color: #fb3a5e;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

At the end I'm expecting this:

```
&:focus,
&:hover,
&.active {
  color: #fb3a5e;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's my config:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-property-sort-order-smacss",
  "plugins": ["stylelint-order", "stylelint-scss"],
  "rules": {
    "color-hex-case": "lower",
    "block-no-empty": true,
    "font-weight-notation": "numeric",
    "length-zero-no-unit": true,
    "declaration-block-no-duplicate-properties": true,
    "declaration-colon-space-after": "always",
    "declaration-colon-space-before": "never",
    "declaration-block-semicolon-space-before": "never",
    "declaration-bang-space-before": "always",
    "declaration-block-no-shorthand-property-overrides": true,
    "declaration-empty-line-before": "never",
    "block-opening-brace-newline-after": "always",
    "block-closing-brace-space-before": "always-single-line",
    "block-closing-brace-newline-after": "always",
    "block-closing-brace-newline-before": "always",
    "selector-list-comma-newline-after": "always",
    "rule-empty-line-before": ["always", {
      "except": ["first-nested"]
    }],
    "string-quotes": "single",
    "color-named": "never",
    "indentation": 2,
    "no-invalid-double-slash-comments": true,
    "shorthand-property-no-redundant-values": true,
    "selector-combinator-space-after": "always",
    "selector-combinator-space-before": "always"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`selector-max-empty-lines` rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/selector-max-empty-lines):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-max-empty-lines": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: It has no effect in my case.

Comment: I suggest raising a bug in Stylelint's issue tracker as the rule is intended for this scenario and works that way in the demo - https://stylelint.io/demo/#N4Igxg9gJgpiBcIBk8BmEwFcDOAaAOgHYAERKAFhAG4wBOBhZAdAIZgAuAljccEccUgAbCLXjEAxKgBGAZhYBWGAG5+xdjAAe7ALQshnAOaFxQmKnaqS6rbtiRaLLhBPFCLlUQC+IXCGwAnoTsLJoI4NjYvuAuqEbhfNb4ILSYZtjJ4okCAsnYMGYcojoAtqE6MCUADuwBOgaEMBkIxAAMal7eIF5AA

Comment: Just a note: this rule has been deprecated in 15.0.0+, see: https://stylelint.io/migration-guide/to-15/#deprecated-stylistic-rules.